# Do we need the tag for [flask-blueprints] when there exists one for [flask] already?

Tags: discussion, tags

I tried adding the [flask-blueprints] tag but it says that there is no such tag. So I tried creating one but it didn't allow me and requested that I raise it in the meta forums.

Since flask is a web application framework and flask blueprint is a specific concept of this framework, I believe that both are not synonyms.

Comment: [tag:flask-blueprint] is a synonym for [tag:flask] (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/flask/synonyms)).

Comment: Can the synonym be reviewed because Flask is a web applications framework. And Flask-blueprints is a specific concept in this framework

Comment: Yes, this synonyms can be removed, but I'm not a domain expert so I can't judge if this is needed. If you want to get it done, you should edit your question here to explain why this is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the [flask-blueprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask-blueprint) tag is a ***synonym*** of the master [flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask) tag. The synonym was created way back in December of 2014.

Because it's a synonym, [flask-blueprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask-blueprint) cannot be created in our system as a distinct tag. Any attempt to use the tag [flask-blueprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask-blueprint) will map back to the master tag, [flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask).

Synonyms are commonly created in two cases:

1. Where the two names are obviously synonyms and refer to exactly the same thing.
2. Where there is no need to distinguish between the two names for the purposes of tagging Stack Overflow questions.

The second case perhaps requires a bit more elaboration. Tags exist to categorize questions, helping folks to find questions either to answer or to learn from. Having too many narrowly-scoped tags actually makes questions more difficult to find, so concepts that aren't really distinct from the larger umbrella will sometimes be made synonyms of the umbrella tag. Although I am not familiar with the subject matter under consideration here, it appears that is what happened in this case.

If you believe that there is a legitimate need to uniquely categorize questions about Flask Blueprints, please make an argument toward that end, including a list of questions that should get that tag. A moderator can then remove the synonym, allowing the [flask-blueprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask-blueprint) tag to be created on its own.